# Want to print HQ one image as (9) 8.5 x 11 sheets

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, slices

I have an image that has been sitting on my computer for a while. I want to cut this image into 9 smaller images, severed into 3 columns of 3 rows. I have tried using Easy Poster  Printer, however the result was not high quality.:

[image]

[image]

I'm open to using the slice tool, however the slices from the original image always save as smaller.

How can I print this image as I have mentioned, while keeping the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

I always use a spreadsheet!

While this is not what a spreadsheet is designed for, I find it really does work.

Open a new spreadsheet, and turn on page gridlines. In excel you can do this on the Page Layout tab and then tick and untick the "Gridlines: Print" section:

[image]

Next setup your page size. Mine defaults to A4 (210mm x 297mm) but your may default to 8.5" by 11" if that is a common size.

Now, insert the image. I chose a 121 MP image of earth to insert.

[image]

As you can see, it spans many pages. I now set the margins to narrow, as my printer can cope, and make it as big as I can within the 3x3 page limit. You may find changing the paper orientation to landscape will allow to you make the image slightly larger. This depends on page length ratios and image length ratios.

It's sensible now to print to a PDF, or a file, to check it looks okay.

[image]

If you want each image, upload the PDF to an image extract program - I like [SmallPDF](https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-jpg).

If you want it on paper, then check the edges will line up, and hit print!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to solve my problem! Now, I rarely use excel. How do I align the grid in the 3 column, 3 row structure like you did?

Comment: @FrockWellington That's the page view - when you zoom out the other lines disappear.

Comment: Ok so I'm in the view tab. How do I go from here?

Comment: @FrockWellington Go to the Page Layout tab - under the word "Team" is the word "Guidelines". Under that is Print - tick it then untick it. I've edited the image.

Comment: I see that and have it checked. Now what?

Comment: @FrockWellington Now insert the image... Follow the instructions in the answer.

Comment: I apologize for being such a bother. I still do not know how you changed your page size in step 2 to slice the image in place.

Comment: @FrockWellington It's fine, I'm happy to help. I did not change the paper size. It should be set to the page size that you need. If you click File -> Print and look at the preview, the image should be split across the pages. If it looks okay you could print it.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was how did you get those gridlines along the image as opposed to the normal cells?

Comment: @FrockWellington I just zoomed out... they're the page grid lines, they show up as dotted lines zoomed in.

Comment: @Metasomatism - this has got to be one of the most novel uses of Excel I have ever seen!

Comment: @Metasomatism I feel so bad for dragging this out anymore. My picture is on the gridlines. I have tried zooming out, but it does not realign them into the 3 * 3 order. Talk to me like I'm 3. lol

Comment: @FrockWellington No, you need to resize it yourself. Simply click it and then resize it by holding Shift + dragging the bottom right corner circle.